# Outer Method Inside Inner Class

Tags: python, oop

Say I have 3 classes: Car (outer), Engine (inner) and Brake (another inner). I'll never use Engine or Brake in any context that I'm not already using Car.

Plus, Car does a heavy job (like read a big CSV file). I want to call it only once in my code, and then work this data with Engine and Brake.

Finally, there's a function I know I will use either in Engine or Brake, so I suppose I should create it in Car and then make Engine and Brake child class from Car.

My code:

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self,foo,bar):
        self.foo = foo
        self.bar = bar
        
    def some_method(self):
        print('im outer but used inner')
        
    class Engine():
        def __init__(self):
            self.some_method()
    
    class Brake():
        def __init__(self):
            self.some_method()
```

If I run:

```
test = Car('a','b')

test.Engine()
```

I got:

```
AttributeError: 'Engine' object has no attribute 'some_method'
```

Where is my error?

Comment: Methods on inner classes  aren't automatically inherited. Just because a car *has an* engine, doesn't mean an engine *is a* car and can do things a car can do.

Comment: `some_method` is a method of `Car`, and an `Engine` is not a `Car`. If you want a method available in several classes, you'd need to explicitly define it in each class, or define it in a base class, and explicitly inherit from the base class in each class.

Comment: inner classes are just using the namespace Car.

Comment: you can use inheritance, then you can use access members of parent class into child classes.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly Car is not an Engine, but Car has an Engine, so you need to do "composition",which is creating an object of Car in Engine class (same thing goes for Brake class), example code:

```
class Car:
      def __init__(self,foo,bar):
          self.foo = foo
          self.bar = bar
        
      def some_method(self):
           print('im outer but used inner')
class Engine:
      def __init__(self):
           self.car=Car() #here i created an object of car inside of Engine class
      def get_method(self):
             self.car.some_method()
```

Definition of composition: Composition is a concept that models a has a relationship. It enables creating complex types by combining objects of other types. This means that a class Composite can contain an object of another class Component. This relationship means that a Composite has a Component.
->source:[https://realpython.com/inheritance-composition-python/#:~:text=Composition%20is%20a%20concept%20that,a%20Composite%20has%20a%20Component%20](https://realpython.com/inheritance-composition-python/#:%7E:text=Composition%20is%20a%20concept%20that,a%20Composite%20has%20a%20Component%20).

Real life example: in real-life, complex objects are often built from smaller, simpler objects. For example, a car is built using a metal frame, an engine, some tires, a transmission, a steering wheel, and a large number of other parts. A personal computer is built from a CPU, a motherboard, some memory, etc… Even you are built from smaller parts: you have a head, a body, some legs, arms, and so on.